# Converting Nginx config to Haproxy

Tags: reverse-proxy, acl, haproxy

I am trying to migrate my reverseproxy from Nginx to Haproxy to use it's health checks, maps and monitoring capabilities.

HAProxy config seems not as straight forward as Nginx. Can someone help me convert below nginx rules to haproxy config.

```
  location = / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_pass https://myapp.azurewebsites.net;
  }
  location /test {
    proxy_pass https://myapp.azurewebsites.net;
  }
  location /test/ {
    proxy_pass https://myapp.azurewebsites.net;
  }
```

So i have same backend for all the rules. I am using below HAProxy config but it's working only for `/test/` but not for `/test`

```
acl is_domain hdr(host) -i www.domain.com
use_backend be_test if is_domain { path -i / } || { path -i -m beg /test} 

backend be_test
mode http
option forwardfor
http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
http-request replace-header Host .* myapp.azurewebsites.net
server srv01 myapp.azurewebsites.net:443 weight 1 maxconn 100  check ssl verify none
```

Answer (score 0):

What does the logs say ?
Not sure `replace-header Host` is required as your Azure website should answer to www.domain.com as a VirtualHost.

Comment: Logs say  404 NOT FOUND and connects to default backend.